# Duvida de comando no Python

Tags: python

Eu estou migrando da programação em batch para o Python, em batch havia o comando "goto", que basicamente criava uma sub-area dentro do comando:

```
goto EXEMPLO
pause

:EXEMPLO
pause
```

Assim, quando o comando chega em "EXEMPLO" ele salta para a linha ":EXEMPLO", é possivel fazer isso no Python? (Uso o 3.6)

Comment: Este exemplo não faz nada útil. Se der um exemplo onde é útil podemos mostrar como fazer em Python. Este é só não fazer nada.

Comment: A ideia é bem simples, vamos dizer que tu tem uma escolha, onde o usuário que está rodando o código pode escolher entre 1 e 2, se for 1 vai para uma certa area do comando, se for 2 vai para outra, depois retorna para o começo e pode fazer a escolha de novo.

Comment: Então coloque este exemplo na pergunta. Se você quer saber uma coisa e pergunta outra, vai receber respostas ruins.

Answer (score 1):

Não. Em Python você deve usar estruturas de repetição e estruturas condicionais para controlar o fluxo do seu código.

Para executar linhas de código caso uma condução seja verdadeira, você faz o seguinte:

```
minhaVariavel = 5

if minhaVariavel == 5:
    print('O valor eh 5')
else:
    print('O valor nao eh 5')
```

Para executar repetidamente um trecho de código enquanto uma condição é verdadeira, você faz o seguinte:

```
minhaVariavel = 0

while minhaVariavel < 5:
    print('O valor eh ' + str(minhaVariavel))
    minhaVariavel += 1
```

E existem muitas outras estruturas de controle.

O site oficial da linguagem tem um tutorial sobre isso, você pode acessar por aqui:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html

**Não esqueça de indentar o seu código!**

Comment: Ah, entendi, que pena, obrigado igualmente, foi muito útil!

Comment: Que bom @Dariusdacosta. Se minha resposta solucionou sua dúvida, não esqueca de marca-la como correta.